# Struggling with proper/efficient structure of firebase realtime database. Is denormalization appropriate in this case?

Tags: json, database, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and was hoping to get some help/direction with my JSON tree. I have read the documentation, watched a few videos, and am struggling mightily.

For my application, the main collections I have are users, organizations, surveys, and observations.

A user will belong to one or more organizations and have multiple surveys. Each survey will have multiple observations.

The most common function would be to get all observations for an organization. The next most common function would be to get all observations for a single user.

The observations collection will certainly be the largest.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
   users
      uid1
         organizations
            orgName1: true
         surveys 
            surveyid1: true
      uid2
      ...
      

   organizations
      orgName1 
         members
            uid1: true
      orgName2
      ...

   surveys
      surveyid1
         uid1: true
         observations
            observationid1: true
      surveyid2
      ...

   observations
      observationid1
         surveyid1: true
      observationid2
      ...
```

Is it too expensive to get all observations for an organization going through member users, then their surveys?

If I have the exact id of something in a collection, will I still need to download the entire collection?

If it is too expensive, in order to bypass user and survey data when fetching observations, would a subnode for observations within the organization and user nodes be appropriate?

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!